# What is the best method to extract live data from an application? (details inside)

Tags: excel, extract, information-extraction

Since I have little experience programming, I first tried posting this "job" on a freelance website. Then, 4 programmers who seemed to what they were doing failed to solve it (maybe they didn't know what they were doing). After this, I decided to attempt it myself, and that is why I came to Stack Overflow, which I believe  will point me in the right direction.

The problem appears quite simple: the program in question gives me rows and columns of data, just like a spreadsheet. As time goes by, new rows are added on top. It looks like this:

[image]

I just need to replicate this data inside an Excel spreadsheet, so that I can perform analysis.

I will keep it short, as I don't know what further detail I could give. Perhaps looking at the program files could help in establishing what sort of program it is. Download link: http://xpproupdate.xpi.com.br/xppro.zip

Thanks!

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: The one in the title? Either way, AnalystCave.com already gave a very satisfactory answer. Thank you for your constructive interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some loose ideas:

### Method 1 (assuming this is an app connected to the Internet):

Try packet-sniffing. Instead of extracting the data from the app download a packet sniffing app and look and the data-flow. See on what `port` the app is exchanging data. If the data is not encryped the tasks should be fairly easy.

As a reference see this packet sniffer in C#: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C

### Method 2 (assuming no connection to the Internet, or if there is encryption involved):

If the data is encrypted or the app simply does not interact with the Internet then try to access the app's `Win32 window handle` and traverse it's internal controls.

### Method 3 (last resort):

Frequent window image screenshot and scraping the data from the image using a simple OCR.